# How to update a custom listview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-service

I have an application developed to get all the third party applications installed and to display them on a list view! this is been done by an extended baseAdapter. In this list I do an uninstallation of a selected application using this code :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + Packname));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Now what I want is to update the list view with the changed data so that the user can get updated application list. how can I achieve this. I found that notifyDatasetchanged method but it can only be used for simple listviews! what are the options that I have and please let me know of any tutorials to achieve my outcome!

thank you.

Comment: Can you provide us some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean only for simple listviews? How is yours different? You should be able to call notifyDataSetChanged on your custom adapter class after deleting one of your items.  You can create a function to do it...

```
private ArrayList<Object> list;

public void deleteItem(int index){
        list.remove(index);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have an adapter (something that extends `BaseAdapter` probably) that you set into the `ListView` using `setAdapter(...)`. add a method to your adapter implementation class that sets the underlying objects that are backing the list. make sure to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end. something like,

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter<String> {
  private List<String> strings;

  ...
  void setModel(List<String> strings) {
    this.strings = strings;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```

simply calling your adapter's `setModel(...)` will cause the `ListView` to update.